# how to import google contacts in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with laravel and I have done login with Google in laravel using socialite. Now I'm trying to get google contacts and I'm using `Artdarek\OAuth` for this. But I'm getting an error

`TokenResponseException in StreamClient.php line 68: Failed to request resource. HTTP Code: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

[here is error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQcg9.png)
I also tried many links, but I don’t know what’s problem with my code.

Comment: 1. Which Laravel version do you use?
2. Can you include a little bit of your code?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.2